# How do I remove enterprise client access features

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

When I downloaded the trial version of SP 2010, it was the first time I ever used it.  When asked for a trial product key, I entered the key for "Enterprise Client Access License Features" when I should have entered the key for "Standard Client Access License features".  What is the best way to resolve this?  Do I need to do a new install and backup/restore my sites, or can I downgrade my current trial?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebuild your SharePoint farm.  Given you did not enable the Enterprise Features on each Site Collection, you'll be able to restore the content databases to the new Standard farm.

Comment: I built a new farm with the purchased license (without the enterprise extensions).  I backed up and tried to restore a site collection to the new farm  I got the error: Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version.  The backup file should be restored to a server with version '14.0.0.4762' or later.  Any suggestions on getting around this?  I'm pretty sure I did not use any enterprise features.